# Site is being redirected to /folder

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, directory

I tried to look for this question everywhere, but was unable to find it but I wanted to quickly get this resolved as it is affecting my site.

Currently I have a VPS website, which I also have a SSL and I want to make sure everything is perfectly set up. The issue that is happening right now is my site is being redirected to a blank folder.

Example:

When typing `example.com` it is going to `https://www.example.com/folder/`

What I want to accomplish is if someone types in `www.example.com` or `example.com` they will go to `https://example.com` and see what ever code is in the index file.

I tried to find the source as to why it is being redirected to /folder and I was unable to. Also when typing in `www.example.com` it goes to `https://www.example.com/index.php` which is also fine but I want to drop the `index.php`.

If you can help me solve this it would mean the world. Especially if it can be done in .htaccess or where ever that is efficient.

Edit .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Edit 2
I added new lines to my htaccess it is still going to `https://www.example.com/folder/` when typing in `example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifesalvation\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lifesalvation.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lifesalvation.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lifesalvation.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there already an `.htaccess` file? If so, can you share that with us?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] t`

Comment: Please if anyone has knowledge about this it would be helpful